# How to extract year or month,day from oracle function without using sub-query?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, timestamp-with-timezone

I have the query below is not working for me,

this function `from_tz(to_timestamp(START_TIME, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 
    substr(UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET,1,3)||':'||'00') at local as local_tstz`
allow me to convert timezones from diffrernt reguins to local,when I try to extract day from this function using `TO_CHAR(from_tz(to_timestamp(START_TIME, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 
    substr(UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET,1,3)||':'||'00') at local as local_tstz,'DD'`)
**it's not possible because it's not a real column , I end up creating new sub-query**,I'm ending up creating many sub queries and **I want to avoid this because 
it make the query complex and it make the query take more longer time**,

```
select from_tz(to_timestamp(START_TIME, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 
substr(UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET,1,3)||':'||'00'),
from_tz(to_timestamp(START_TIME, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 
substr(UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET,1,3)||':'||'00') at local as local_tstz,
to_char(from_tz(to_timestamp(START_TIME, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 
substr(UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET,1,3)||':'||'00') at local as local_tstz,'DD')
from TAPIN_201906@billingdb;
```

Comment: Use a subquery or CTE.

Comment: Time zones are not always full hours from UTC, for example Iran has UTC+04:30 or India has UTC+05:30. You may need to consider this in your code.

Comment: Dear @WernfriedDomscheit I don't have problem with timezone, the problem is the column of timezone it not real column and it's getting it's value from a function `from_tz(to_timestamp(START_TIME, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 
    substr(UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET,1,3)||':'||'00') at local as local_tstz ` so you can't use `TO_CHAR` or `Extract (day from`  normally .

Comment: Where is the problem? It does not matter whether `START_TIME` and `UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET` are columns or functions.

Comment: `START_TIME ` & `UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET ` are real columns .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem in version 19c, or else I don't understand it. Anyway, three remarks:

1) If your START_TIME is really a string, that is just not a good idea at all. Use real DATE or TIMESTAMP datatypes. In your shoes, I would replace both columns by one column with a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE datatype. As it is, you cannot sort properly by date because of the time zone offsets.

2) With your current data, you can simplify the conversion to a local timestamp, as I'll show in a minute.

3) As pointed out in a comment, EXTRACT starts from UTC time, not local time, so I changed my solution back to TO_CHAR.

```
with data(START_TIME, UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET) as (
  select '20001112012345', '+02' from dual
)
select
to_timestamp_TZ(
  START_TIME || substr(UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET,1,3),
  'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSTZH'
)  at local as local_ts,
to_char(
  to_timestamp_TZ(
    START_TIME || substr(UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET,1,3),
    'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSTZH'
  )
  ,'DD'
) as to_char_day,
extract(
  day from
  to_timestamp_TZ(
    START_TIME || substr(UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET,1,3),
    'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSTZH'
  )
) as extract_day
from data;

LOCAL_TS                                   TO_CHAR_DAY EXTRACT_DAY   
2000-11-12 00:23:45,000000000 EUROPE/PARIS 12          11
```

Best regards,
Stew Ashton

Comment: Note, when you use `EXTRACT()` on a `TIMESTAMP WITH {LOCAL} TIME ZONE` value then result refers to UTC time.

Comment: Wernfried, I didn't know that! Thank you for pointing that out. I'm changing my answer to use TO_CHAR.

Comment: My proplem is that I can't extract year or month,day value using `TO_CHAR`  from this function in oracle `TO_CHAR(from_tz(to_timestamp(START_TIME, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 
    substr(UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET,1,3)||':'||'00') at local as local_tstz,'DD')` because it's not a real column  , I will try you solutions thanks =)

Comment: Another option would be `EXTRACT(DAY FROM (CAST(to_timestamp_TZ(...) AT LOCAL) AS TIMESTAMP))`

Comment: Osama, what do you mean by "because it's not a real column"? It's an expression and you can use expressions in those functions. Are you getting an error message? What exactly is that error message? Can you show us how to reproduce it? What is your Oracle version?

Answer (score 0):

Like Stew I don't understand your problem. Of course, the proper solution would be to use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` data type for your columns.

Otherwise you can use a function:

```
create or replace function TO_LOCAL(START_TIME IN DATE, UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET IN integer) return TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE as
begin
    RETURN from_tz(to_timestamp(START_TIME, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 
UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET||':'||'00') at local;
end TO_LOCAL;
```

or you can define a VIRTUAL column of such values.

**Update:**

It does not matter whether `START_TIME` and `UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET` are columns or functions, see this example:

```
create or replace function START_TIME AS NUMBER is
begin
    return TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');
end;
```

You can select such function in the same way as it would be column, there is no difference.

Comment: My proplem is that I can't extract year or month,day value using `TO_CHAR`  from this function in oracle `from_tz(to_timestamp(START_TIME, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 
    substr(UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET,1,3)||':'||'00') at local as local_tstz ` because it's not a real column .

Answer (score 0):

Please expand on your contention that 'I can't extract year or month,day ... because it's not a real column'. That seems as though you think the FROM parameter of the must be an actual table column. But this in not true. As long as the parameter satisfies the EXTRACT data requirement is can be used. For your case see below:

```
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
declare 
     UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET varchar2(3) := '-05';
     start_date           varchar2(14);

     function get_some_date 
       return  varchar
     as 
     begin 
         return to_char(sysdate + dbms_random.value(1000,10000), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')  ;
    end get_some_date;    

begin
   for i in 1 .. 10
   loop 
       start_date := get_some_date; 
       dbms_output.put( 'Date is ' || to_date(start_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));   
       dbms_output.put( ' Extract month is ' ||  EXTRACT( month FROM (from_tz(to_timestamp( start_date, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), substr(UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET,1,3)||':'||'00'))) );
       dbms_output.put( ' Extract year is '  ||  EXTRACT( year  FROM (from_tz(to_timestamp( start_date, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), substr(UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET,1,3)||':'||'00'))) );
       dbms_output.put( ' Extract day is '   ||  EXTRACT( day   FROM (from_tz(to_timestamp( start_date, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), substr(UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET,1,3)||':'||'00'))) );
       dbms_output.put_line('.');
   end loop;
end ;
```

Notice the parentheses surrounding the FROM parameter of the EXTRACT function.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution for my case using the below code

```
 to_char(from_tz(to_timestamp(START_TIME, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 
 substr(UTC_TIME_CODE_OFFSET,1,3)||':'||'00') at local,'yyyymmdd') as local_tstz
```

I was able to extract year, month and day from a not real column,at least this solution avoid me make sub-query for the above case.